# use exclam (!) syntax for factorial in python

Tags: python, syntax, operator-overloading, factorial

Can a working factorial function/operator be defined with a syntax like in mathematics?  i.e. using the `!` symbol.

I can't think of any use cases of the existing symbol where things could be ambiguous

- ipython `!shell_escape` always has the bang at the start of a line
- something like `0!=1` would be `True` as usual because the other interpretation of `factorial(0) = 1` would be `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal` or similar error)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean, "can I define the ! operator in my Python program?," the answer is no, Python doesn't have a bang operator that can be defined.

If you mean, "could Python be extended to include a ! operator?," the answer is yes, though probably not as a postfix operator like `x!`.  I very much doubt that the Python community would agree it was a good idea and move ahead with it though.

Answer (score 6):

You [can not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932328/python-defining-my-own-operators) define new operators in Python. Instead, either provide a `factorial` function or simply use [`math.factorial`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.factorial).