# How to change the look of Python operators?

Tags: python, customization

In order to make Python look more familiar, I've tried to assign an operator symbol to a variable's name,just for educational purposes: `import operator` `equals = operator.eq`
This seems to work fine for `equals(a,b)` but not for `a equals b`

Is there a way to express that `a equals b` instead of `a == b`

Answer (score 4):

No, Python (and most mainstream languages) does not allow this kind of customization. In Python the restriction is quite intentional — an expression such as `a equals b` would look ungrammatical to any reader familiar with Python.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, but [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932580/1730261) shows how you can use [this simple trick](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122/) to "create" new operators. However, they only work if you surround the operator by `| |` or by `<< >>`:

```
equals = Infix(lambda x, y: x == y):
print 2 |equals| 2 # True
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is

```
def equals(a,b):
    return a == b

equals(1,5)
>> False
```

or

```
class my:
value = 0
def equals(self, b):
    return self.value == b

a = my()

a.equals(3)
>>False
```

But you should use the built-in operator for readability. This way, a reader can distinguish, at once, an operator, a function, a symbol (a variable), a member function, etc...

Comment: You could, however, write the script your way and then use another script to replace equals with =. But I don't recommend that.