# Adding a new binary operator to Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, vector, operator-overloading, operators

I would like to use an operator such as 'x' to give the cross-product of two vectors. Is there any way to add such an operator to Python 3?

Comment: Is there a reason why a simple method like `vec1.cross(vec2)` isn't sufficient enough for you? It's not much harder than `vec1 x vec2`

Comment: I don't want to dupe-hammer this, but look here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932328/python-defining-my-own-operators

Comment: If you are on python 3.5+, you might like to use `__matmul__`, see [PEP-0465](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)

Comment: @Markus Meskanen If we didn't have handy operators we'd be writing two.plus(two) == 4. It's easier to follow calculations if the code resembles the corresponding mathematic expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot supplement Python's set of operators and statements directly in the Python code. However, you can write a wrapper that uses Python's [language services](http://docs.python.org/3/library/language.html) to write a Pythonesque DSL which includes the operators you want.