# Shorter alternative for 'lambda' keyword?

Tags: python, lambda, programming-languages, keyword

#### Background:

Python is about simplicity and readable code. It has gotten better over the versions and I am a huge fan! However, typing `l` `a` `m` `b` `d` `a` every time I have to define a lambda is not fun (you may disagree).
The problem is, these 6 characters `l` `a` `m` `b` `d` `a` make my statements longer, especially if I nest a couple of lambdas inside `map`s and `filter`s.
I am not nesting more than 2 or three, because it takes away the readability of python, even then typing `l` `a` `m` `b` `d` `a` feels too verbose.

#### The actual question (is in comments):

```
# How to rename/alias a keyword to a nicer one? 
lines = map(lmd x: x.strip(), sys.stdin)

# OR, better yet, how to define my own operator like -> in python?
lines = map(x -> x.strip(), sys.stdin)
# Or may be :: operator is pythonic
lines = map(x :: x.strip(), sys.stdin)

# INSTEAD of this ugly one. Taking out this is my goal!
lines = map(lambda x: x.strip(), sys.stdin)
```

I am happy to add import like this:

```
from myfuture import lmd_as_lambda
# OR
from myfuture import lambda_operator
```

Comment: *“when I nest a couple of lambdas inside maps and filters”* Use generator expressions instead?

Comment: Write functions instead of lambdas. They are easier to debug. Lambdas are useful, but ought to be used in moderation. If typing lambda is too troublesome, perhaps that is a sign that you are using them too much.

Comment: What's wrong with passing `str.strip`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's not equivalent to `lambda x: x.strip()`. There could be `bytes` (python-3.x) or `unicode`s (python-2.x) in there - or something else entirely that can be stripped. It's unlikely (impossible?) for `sys.stdin` but it could be problematic in more general cases.

Comment: Other than by avoiding its use, there's no way for you to abbreviate a Python keyword. Unlike C/C++, there's no preprocessor step that expands macros.

Comment: re: __What's wrong with passing str.strip__ : Thanks but `lambda x: x.strip()`  used here is a placeholder or demo example and this question is for all lambdas in general and not a sepcific lambda. Are we going to find alternatives like `str.strip` for all the custom lambdas? I dont think so!

Comment: I know it’s an old question, but in the pursuit of a language with terse syntax—especially for lambdas—I found Scala (where you can do things like `val doubled = ints.map(_ * 2)`) and a package to do the same for Julia: https://juliapackages.com/p/lambdafn. Not sure any of these innovations will ever be a part of Python, but one can dream. 

Comment: @KevinLi , I totally agree. I've went from Python to Scala and now back to Python, and Python inline functions now seem very verbose. I'm really hoping there will be a PEP to introduce something more succinct in the future

Comment: There was [PEP-677](https://peps.python.org/pep-0677/#compatibility-with-arrow-based-lambda-syntax) for similar syntax to replace `Callable` and it was [rejected](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/NHCLHCU2XCWTBGF732WESMN42YYVKOXB/). Looks unliklely we'll be getting a nicer syntax for this any time soon

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The good news is: You don't need to use `map` or `filter` at all, you can use [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) (lazy) or [list comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) (eager) instead and thus avoid `lambda`s completely.

So instead of:

```
lines = map(lambda x: x.strip(), sys.stdin)
```

Just use:

```
# You can use either of those in Python 2 and 3, but map has changed between
# Python 2 and Python 3 so I'll present both equivalents:
lines = (x.strip() for x in sys.stdin)  # generator expression (Python 3 map equivalent)
lines = [x.strip() for x in sys.stdin]  # list comprehension   (Python 2 map equivalent)
```

It's probably also faster if you use comprehensions. Very few functions are actually faster when used in `map` or `filter` - and using a `lambda` there is more of an anti-pattern (and slow).

---

The question only contained an example for `map`, but you can also replace `filter`. For example if you want to `filter` out odd numbers:

```
filter(lambda x: x%2==0, whatever)
```

You can use a conditional comprehension instead:

```
(x for x in whatever if x%2==0)
[x for x in whatever if x%2==0]
```

---

You could even combine a `map` and `filter` in one comprehension:

```
(x*2 for x in whatever if x%2==0)
```

Just consider how that would look like with `map` and `filter`:

```
map(lambda x: x*2, filter(lambda x: x%2==0, whatever))
```

---

Note: That doesn't mean `lambda` isn't useful! There are lots of places where `lambda`s are very handy. Consider the [`key` argument for `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) (and likewise for `min` and `max`) or [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) (but better keep away from that function, most of the times a normal `for`-loop is more readable) or `itertools` that require a predicate function: [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile), [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile). Just to name a few examples where a `lambda` could be useful, there are probably lots of other places as well.

Comment: Thanks. Today I learned  [Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), it solves my need.  I would accept this answer in a short while. waiting to see if somebody has thoughts about `::` or `->` operators)

Comment: Python 2 supports [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?#generator-expressions), too, so what you said about them and Python 3 is incorrect.

Comment: @martineau I never said python-2.x doesn't support generators expressions. All I said (and meant) was that the equivalent for `map` is a list-comprehension in python-2.x and a generator expression in python-3.x

Comment: You seem to be saying that a generator expression would not also be equivalent in Python 2.

Comment: @martineau It's not equivalent to `map` on python-2.x. But that doesn't mean there are no generator expressions in python-2.x. I've updated the answer and clarified it a bit. Please let me know if it's still ambiguous.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question I came here for (short hand for lambda), but I've learned about generator expressions. So I'm at peace today. +1

Comment: doesn't answer the question - i already use generators. I really want answer to the question itself:  how to shorten the `lambda` which is distracting when used over and again

Comment: @javadba the answer, implicitly, is that there is no way. And there are no future plans to add a way. Indeed, Guido almost removed lambda entirely from Python 3

Comment: Yes - I do not miss Guido and the BDFL. The popularity of python is surprising given its hostility to  functional programming. TIt seems to be coming from a mantra of "one way to do things" and that one way is the quite limited `for comprehensions`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001986/left-to-right-application-of-operations-on-a-list-in-python3

Answer (score 9):

To answer your specific question, the `operator` module provides several functions intended to replace specific uses of a `lambda` expression. Here, you can use the `methodcaller` function to create a function that calls a given method on an object.

```
from operator import methodcaller as mc

lines = map(mc('strip'), sys.stdin)
```

However, list comprehensions tend to be preferred to many, if not most, uses of `map`.

```
lines = [x.strip() for x in sys.stdin]
```

Comment: Yes, the `operator` module is very handy for `map` etc. In this case one could also consider using `str.strip` directly (if there are only pure `str`s).

Comment: Good point. `methodcaller` is useful when you need to rely on duck typing (i.e., I don't know what type `x` will have, but I know it needs to have a `strip` method) or when you need to pass additional arguments to the method. Otherwise, you can use an unbound method as the function argument.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 1. Method caller may not be always possible, for instance, if my lambda takes a tuple and swap positions and returns a new tuple. 2. `[x.strip() for x in sys.stdin]` this is elegant but my data streams are lazily `yield`ed from generator.  I just learned from @MSeifert answer that  python 3 supports lazy evaluations when I swap `[]` with `()`

Comment: @ThammeGowda Just to clarify: Both python-2.x and 3.x support generator expressions (lazy evaluation). What I meant was that `map` and `filter` are eager in python-2.x but lazy in python-3.x.

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks. Yes, Just looked it up, it was accepted in 2.4 as PEP-289 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Comment: Python 2 has `itertools.imap`, which is the equivalent of Python 3's `map` for working with arbitrary iterables (including generator expressions). For your tuple-swapping function, try `operator.itemgetter`: `map(itemgetter(1,0), [(1, 'a'), (2,'b')])`. That said, there are cases where you can't avoid writing a user-defined function, but the reason to avoid them where possible is that there is significant overhead to calling a user-defined function; the function returned by `itemgetter(1,0)` should be faster than `lambda (x,y): (y, x)`.

Comment: This is actually a partial answer to the original question. What about general `lambda` that may not be a simple method invocation -and thus not fit precisely into a `methodcaller`?

Comment: In general, the only reasonable option is to replace the lambda expression with the name of a previously defined function.

Answer (score 8):

As a person who never uses lambdas in his code except for debugging purposes, I can suggest several alternatives.

I won't speak about [defining your own syntax in an editor](https://youtu.be/pkCLMl0e_0k?t=6290) (you can't define operators in a pure Python though: [Python: defining my own operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932328/python-defining-my-own-operators)) but just about built-in stuff.

1. **Methods of [built-in types](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)**:
   Compare the following:

   ```
   words = ['cat', 'dog', 'shark']
   result_1 = map(lambda x: x.upper(), words)
   result_2 = (x.upper() for x in words)
   result_3 = map(str.upper, words)
   # ['CAT', 'DOG', 'SHARK']
   ```

   Using `map` with `str.upper` is shorter than both `map` with `lambda` and a generator expression proposed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45766630/7851470).
   You can find lots of other methods in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) for different types such as `int`, `float`, `str`, `bytes` and others, which you can use in the same manner. For example, checking if numbers are integers:

   ```
   numbers = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5]
   result_1 = map(lambda x: x.is_integer(), numbers)
   result_2 = (x.is_integer() for x in numbers)
   result_3 = map(float.is_integer, numbers)
   # [True, False, True, False]
   ```
2. [**Class methods**](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects):
   In a similar way you can use `map` with class methods:

   ```
   class Circle:
       def __init__(self, radius):
           self.radius = radius
       def area(self):
           return 3.14 * self.radius ** 2

   circles = [Circle(2), Circle(10)]
   result_1 = map(lambda x: x.area(), circles)
   result_2 = (x.area() for x in circles)
   result_3 = map(Circle.area, circles)
   # [12.56, 314.0]
   ```
3. **[`operator`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) module:**

   - [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):
     This one is used when you want to select elements by their indices:

     ```
     from operator import itemgetter

     numbers = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6, 7],
                [8, 9, 0, 1]]
     result_1 = map(lambda x: x[0], numbers)
     result_2 = (x[0] for x in numbers)
     result_3 = map(itemgetter(0), numbers)
     # [0, 4, 8]
     ```

     While it is longer than generator expression in the given example, it will actually be shorter when you want to select several elements at once:

     ```
     result_1 = map(lambda x: (x[0], x[2], x[3]), numbers)
     result_2 = ((x[0], x[2], x[3]) for x in numbers)
     result_3 = map(itemgetter(0, 2, 3), numbers)
     # [(0, 2, 3), (4, 6, 7), (8, 0, 1)]
     ```

     You can also use `itemgetter` with dictionaries:

     ```
     data = [{'time': 0, 'temperature': 290, 'pressure': 1.01},
             {'time': 10, 'temperature': 295, 'pressure': 1.04},
             {'time': 20, 'temperature': 300, 'pressure': 1.07}]

     result_1 = map(lambda x: (x['time'], x['pressure']), data)
     result_2 = ((x['time'], x['pressure']) for x in data)
     result_3 = map(itemgetter('time', 'pressure'), data)
     # [(0, 1.01), (10, 1.04), (20, 1.07)]
     ```
   - [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter)
     This one is used to get attributes of objects:

     ```
     from collections import namedtuple
     from operator import attrgetter

     Person = namedtuple('Person', ['name', 'surname', 'age', 'car'])
     people = [Person(name='John', surname='Smith', age=40, car='Tesla'), 
               Person(name='Mike', surname='Smith', age=50, car=None)]
     result_1 = map(lambda x: (x.name, x.age, x.car), people)
     result_2 = ((x.name, x.age, x.car) for x in people)
     result_3 = map(attrgetter('name', 'age', 'car'), people)
     # [('John', 40, 'Tesla'), ('Mike', 50, None)]
     ```

     It is longer than the generator expression version, so I'm leaving it here just for completeness. Of course, you can import `attrgetter` as `get` and it will be shorter but nobody really does that. Using `attrgetter` has an advantage, though, that you could take it out as a separate callable that could be used more than once (same as `lambda`):

     ```
     get_features = attrgetter('name', 'age', 'car')
     group_1_features = map(get_features, people)
     group_2_features = map(get_features, other_people)
     ...
     ```

     Another alternative worth to mention is using [`fget`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) method of properties:

     ```
     result = map(Person.age.fget, people)
     ```

     I've never seen anyone using it though, so prepare to give explanation to people who will read your code if you use it.
   - [`contains`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.contains):
     Used to check if an element is present in another object/container:

     ```
     from functools import partial
     from operator import contains

     fruits = {'apple', 'peach', 'orange'}
     objects = ['apple', 'table', 'orange']
     result_1 = map(lambda x: x in fruits, objects)
     result_2 = (x in fruits for x in objects)
     is_fruit = partial(contains, fruits)
     result_3 = map(is_fruit, objects)
     # [True, False, True]
     ```

     This, though, has a drawback of creating an additional [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) object. Another way to write this would be to use [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method:

     ```
     result = map(fruits.__contains__, objects)
     ```

     But some people argue that it is a bad practice to use dunder methods as those are just for a private use.
   - Mathematical operations:
     For example, if you would want to sum pairs of numbers, you could use [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.add):

     ```
     from itertools import starmap
     from operator import add

     pairs = [(1, 2), (4, 3), (1, 10), (2, 5)]
     result_1 = map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], pairs)
     result_2 = (x + y for x, y in pairs)
     result_3 = starmap(add, pairs)
     # [3, 7, 11, 7]
     ```

     If you are fine with two additional imports then this is the shortest option. Note that we use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) here because we need to unpack tuples of numbers before supplying them to `add(a, b)` function.

---

I think I covered most of the cases that I constantly encounter that could be rewritten without `lambda`. If you know more, please, write it in a comment, and I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that using unbound methods as arguments is a lot more restrictive than `lambda` or comprehensions, because you're now limited to one type only (or in case of self-defined classes that it duck-types correctly). For example `str.upper` will only work for strings, itwon't work if you have other types in the list, for example bytes or mixed type-lists.