# Getting values from a dict according to a list of keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list.

```
mapper = {"a": 9, "b": 7}
A = ["a", "b"]
```

And I want to get:

```
result = [9, 7]
```

I know there are multiple ways to achieve that, like:

```
result = [mapper[char] for char in A]
result = list(map(lambda x: mapper[x], A))
```

For the second way, could we use `operator` module instead of using lambda?

I found a method called `operator.getitem()`,and I try to use

```
result = list(map(operator.getitem(mapper), A))
```

But this will raise an exception.

I know `list(map(lambda x: operator.getitem(mapper, x), A))` will work, but I just want to avoid using `lambda`.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766630/shorter-alternative-for-lambda-keyword), but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Something like `itertools.starmap(operator.getitem, zip(itertools.repeat(mapper), A))` should do. But the list comprehension is clearly a lot easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) (notice the second form, where it returns multiple items):

```
>>> operator.itemgetter(*A)(mapper)
(9, 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness:

> I find a method called `operator.getitem()`, and I try to use `result = list(map(operator.getitem(mapper), A))`

What went wrong here is that you want to pass `mapper` and one of the elements of `A` as two separate arguments each time - so you can't actually call the function in advance, but instead need to "bind" the `mapper` argument to the call.

For this, we use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
import functools, operator

list(map(functools.partial(operator.getitem, mapper), A))
```

Awkward, but doable. This is why list comprehensions are much more Pythonic.

(`operator.itemgetter` can indeed do the whole thing in one shot as shown; but it's more commonly used when the element to access is fixed and the *container* varies - in particular, to sort a nested container by some key.)