# How to implement infix operator matrix multiplication in Python 2?

Tags: python, numpy, operators, python-2.x, matrix-multiplication

I have been using python 3.7 for a few months, but I recently had to shift to python 2.7. Since I am developing scientific code, I heavily rely on the use of infix operator `@` to multiply nd-arrays. This operator was introduced with python 3.5 (see [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)), therefore, I cannot use it with my new setup.

The obvious solution is to replace all `M1 @ M2` by `numpy.matmul(M1, M2)`, which severely limits my code's readability.

I saw this [hack](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122-infix-operators/) which consists in defining an Infix class allowing to create custom operators by overloading `or` and `ror` operators. My question is: How could I use this trick to make an infix `|at|` operator working just like `@`?

What I tried is:

```
import numpy as np

class Infix:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
    def __ror__(self, other):      
        return Infix(lambda x, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, x))
    def __or__(self, other):
        return self.function(other)
    def __call__(self, value1, value2):
        return self.function(value1, value2)

# Matrix multiplication
at = Infix(lambda x,y: np.matmul(x,y))

M1 = np.ones((2,3))
M2 = np.ones((3,4))

print(M1 |at| M2)
```

When I execute this code, I get :

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (3,4)
```

I think I have an idea of what is not working. When I only look at `M1|at`, I can see that it is a 2*3 array of functions:

```
array([[<__main__.Infix object at 0x7faa1c0d6da0>,
        <__main__.Infix object at 0x7faa1c0d6860>,
        <__main__.Infix object at 0x7faa1c0d6828>],
       [<__main__.Infix object at 0x7faa1c0d6f60>,
        <__main__.Infix object at 0x7faa1c0d61d0>,
        <__main__.Infix object at 0x7faa1c0d64e0>]], dtype=object)
```

This is not what I expected, since I would like my code to consider this 2d-array as a whole, and not element-wise...

Does anybody have a clue of what I should do?

PS: I also considered using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20667084), but I have to avoid the use of external modules.

Comment: This kind of thing is a lot more likely to cause problems than to solve them. `numpy.matmul` is your best option, besides getting back on 3.x. (NumPy doesn't even support 2.x any more. You're going to have more and more compatibility problems trying to get things done on 2.x as time goes on.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Shifting back to 2.x was not a choice, since I now develop code on virtual machines owned and administrated by my company. I think I will use ```numpy.matmul``` as you suggest, but this is likely to be uncomfortable...

Comment: Example problem: `|` has the wrong precedence for your needs. `A + B@C` means what you think it does, but `A + B|at|C` would mean `(A+B)|at|C` even if you got this working. With `matmul`, at least once you parse the code in your head, it's clear what's an argument to what.

Comment: See if you can get Python 3 in the VMs. (You don't need root to do it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem [here](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577201-infix-operators-for-numpy-arrays/).

As suggested in the comments, the ideal fix would either be to use Python 3.x or to use `numpy.matmul`, but this code seems to work, and even has the right precedence :

```
import numpy as np

class Infix(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, function):
        obj = np.ndarray.__new__(cls, 0)
        obj.function = function
        return obj
    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.function = getattr(obj, 'function', None)
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return Infix(lambda x, self=self, other=other: self.function(other, x))
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.function(other)
    def __call__(self, value1, value2):
        return self.function(value1, value2)

at = Infix(np.matmul)

M1 = np.ones((2,3))
M2 = np.ones((3,4))
M3 = np.ones((2,4))

print(M1 *at* M2)
print(M3 + M1 *at* M2)
```