# Arithmetic operators

Tags: python, math, operators, calculation, arithmetic-expressions

As you know there are arithmetic operators like `+` or `-`.
Is there a way to create my own operator which can execute a specific task between two variables?

For example:

```py
a, b = 2, 5
a '+' b == 7
```

What I would like to do:

```py
a 'my own operator' b == some_specific_value
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [recipe](https://github.com/ActiveState/code/blob/master/recipes/Python/384122_Infix_operators/recipe-384122.py) for how to mimic custom infix operators. It creates a custom class `Infix` and implements the `__or__` and `__ror__` methods which then allows to write things in the following way:

```py
add = Infix(lambda x,y: x+y)
result = 1 |add| 2
```

Answer (score 1):

your question as already been answered here:
[Python: defining my own operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932328/python-defining-my-own-operators)

A little addition to what was said on that tread would be that if you define custom objects then you can define the effect of an operator between two objects of the same type:

```
class Complex:
      def __init__(self,real,imaginary):
            self.real=real
            self.imaginary= imaginary 
      def __add__(var):
            c=Complex(self.real + var.real,self.imaginary +v.imaginary)
            return c
```

This code snippet is a common example that creates a class that describes complex numbers and allowes you to do `Complex_c=Complex_a+Complex_b` store the complex sum in `Complex_c`

Comment: Although complex numbers are already there: `print((1+1j) + (1-1j))` prints `(2+0j)`. Also "imaginary" has only one 'm'.

Comment: Sorry for the „m“ abundance!