# How to define custom operator in python

Tags: python, operators

For example, there already exist `+`, `-`... which can be overwritten using `__add__` and `__sub__` respectively. However, is it possible to write a new operator like `.` or `x`?

Comment: No.  There are only specific operators that can be overwritten.  Python doesn't let you add your own.  You cannot change the grammar of the language.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot, [although there's some weird hackyness than can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932328/python-defining-my-own-operators),

But if you want smt like:

```py
1 x 2
```

You'll have to make a [preprocessor](https://wikiless.tiekoetter.com/wiki/Preprocessor?lang=en)